# why keys() of dictionary in python returns in a different order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary `a` and tried to use method `keys()` to return its keys. Below is what I got. I notice the output of `keys()` are not in alphabetical order or original order as in the dictionary.

```
a
Out[1]: {1: 'JAN', 2: 'FEB', 3: 'MAR', 'APR': 4, 'MAY': 5}

a.keys()
Out[2]: ['APR', 1, 2, 3, 'MAY']
```

Anyone could help me understand why this happens. and what's the order keys() is using here?

Comment: No order at all.... That's because python dictionaries are not key-ordered... You were just lucky first time. :p

Comment: because its not , you need to sort it `>>> a={1: 'JAN', 2: 'FEB', 3: 'MAR', 'APR': 4, 'MAY': 5}
>>> sorted(a.keys())
[1, 2, 3, 'APR', 'MAY']
`

Comment: @littlejoshua dictionaries **are not** ordered: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html `the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it)`

Comment: use ordereddict instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary in python using hashes for keys, and it doesn't saves order. So, you cant count on keys order - it may differ during runs and calls.
If you need hashmap *and* save order, you should use [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)